# Importing XML data into MS Access runtime error

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, import, stylesheet

When importing using the MS Access wizard, all goes well. I specify the XML and XSLT files that create the two tables. Saving the import steps and trying to run that fails. Here is an example XML and XSLT files, respectively. MS Access brings in the Errors as a separate table using the PWSID and VIOID values as the key.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Violations>
     <Violation>
      <ViolationDetail>
       <PWSID>TX9999999</PWSID>
       <VIOID>123456789</VIOID>
       <DATAORIGINCODE>S</DATAORIGINCODE>
       <CCODE>7500</CCODE>
       <VCODE>75</VCODE>
       <BEGINDATE>2015-04-28</BEGINDATE>
       <Errors>
          <Error>
            <ErrorDescription>
                Error description here
            </ErrorDescription>
            <ErrorCode>ERR0037</ErrorCode>
            </Error>
       </Errors>
      </ViolationDetail>
     </Violation>
     <Violation>
      <ViolationDetail>
       <PWSID>TX9999999</PWSID>
       <VIOID>234567890</VIOID>
       <DATAORIGINCODE>S</DATAORIGINCODE>
       <CCODE>7500</CCODE>
       <VCODE>71</VCODE>
       <BEGINDATE>2015-05-15</BEGINDATE>
       <Errors>
          <Error>
            <ErrorDescription>
                Error description here
            </ErrorDescription>
            <ErrorCode>ERR0048</ErrorCode>
            </Error>
       </Errors>
      </ViolationDetail>
     </Violation>
    </Violations>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <dataroot>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </dataroot>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ERRORS">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ERROR">
            <ERROR>
                <PWSID><xsl:value-of select="../../PWSID"/></PWSID>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                <VIOID><xsl:value-of select="../../VIOID"/></VIOID>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </ERROR>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My attempt at the VBA code is this which I modified from a solution found thru searches:

```vb
Public Sub importErrorFiles()
    ' REFERENCE MS XML, v6.0
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Dim strFileXML As String, strFileXSL As String
    Dim strPathXML As String, strPathXSL As String

    strPathXSL = CurrentProject.Path & "\xslSheets\"
    strPathXML = CurrentProject.Path & "\workingReports\"
    strFileXML = Dir(strPathXML & "*.xml")

    While strFileXML <> ""
        ' REINITIALIZE DOM OBJECTS
        Set xslDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

        strFileXSL = strPathXSL & Replace(strFileXML, "xml", "xslt")

        If fileExists(strFileXSL) Then

            ' LOAD XML SOURCE
            xmlDoc.Load strPathXML & strFileXML

            ' LOAD XSL FILE
            xslDoc.Load strPathXSL & strFileXSL

            ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
            xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
            newDoc.Save strPathXML & "temp.xml"

            ' APPEND TO TABLES
            Application.ImportXML strPathXML & "temp.xml", acAppendData
            strFile = Dir()
        End If
    Wend

   ' RELEASE DOM OBJECTS
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

The error occurs on the `transformNodeToObject` line:

> The Stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet appears to be empty, or it may not be a well formed XML document.

Oh and `fileExists` is a boolean function that does work.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: *MS Access brings in the Errors as a separate table* - not sure what this means. Is `Errors` your import XML data? Or does this refer to error messages / import errors?

Comment: The wizard creates Errors as the child table which it is since there can be more than one error posted. THe XML document has "Errors" and "Error" tags/nodes.